# Origen y etimología de "turulato"

Tags: etimología, adjetivos

Este fin de semana vi la palabra *turulato* y me preguntaba cuál podría ser el origen de dicha palabra. Os pongo la información que he ido recopilando.

> **[turulato, ta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ayU5TuI)**
>
> 1. adj. coloq. Alelado, estupefacto.

Primera entrada en el DLE en el *Academia suplemento* de 1852:

> TURULATO, TA. adj. fam. Alelado, sobrecogido, estupefacto.

Primera aparición en el CORDE:

> *Por una parte es verdad
>
>   que el mérito es quien merezca,
>
>   y por otra parte, yo,
>
>   señora, es la vez primera
>
>   que enamoro y estoy todo
>
>   turulato.*
>
> Ramón de la Cruz, "El caballero de Medina", 1764 (España).

Primera aparición en la hemeroteca de la BNE:

> *En esto se despidió, dexándome medio turulato, y al instante me propuse contarse á vmd. este cuento [...].*
>
> Diario de Madrid. 2/12/1807, página 1.

Posibles acepciones que han ido apareciendo en el DLE:

- 1884: De *atortolado*.
- 1899-1956: Del latín *turbulentātus*, "turbado".
- 1970-1984: De la onomatopeya *tur*.
- 1992-hoy: Sin etimología.

Así pues, ¿cuál explicación os parece más plausible? ¿Qué otras posibles etimologías se conocen o proponen en otros diccionarios o textos de consulta? ¿Existe algún texto antiguo que pueda aportar algo más de luz sobre el origen de la palabra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corominas, en su Diccionario Etimológico, indica:

> TURULATO, voz de creación expresiva ... pertenece a un grupo de nombres del hombre falto de juicio que evocan las voces sin significado con que se tararea una canción, sugiriendo así la frivolidad y la falta de sentido.
>   ...
>   No anduvo afortunado el académico que en una edición antigua del diccionario dijo que venía de atortolado, pero más extravagante es deducirlo de un lat. **turbulentatus*, como aparece en la última ed. Spitzer (RFE XIII, 121n.) dijo que era voz onomatopéyica, lo cual es indudable si lo tomamos en un sentido amplio.